# How to add copy paste functionality in xamarin (for both android and ios)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my project, I have one entry containing link and one "Copy" button. On "Copy" button i want to copy the link so I can paste it anywhere like in browser or in message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27570497/how-do-you-allow-users-to-copy-and-paste-from-an-xamarin-forms-label  may help you

Comment: When you mean "Both for iOS and Android", you mean for Xamarin.forms or you need the code for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS ?

Comment: Do you need this for Xamarin Forms or Xamarin.Android and Xamarion.iOS? Also what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use clipboard manager class.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.ClipboardManager/

Add text to clipboard so that the user can paste it anywhere.

**CODE :**

```
ClipboardManager clipboard= (ClipboardManager)GetSystemService(Context.ClipboardService);
clipboard.Text = "YOUR TEXT";
```

Comment: "Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer."

Comment: Thanks Marimba for your suggestion. Updated my answer

Comment: Great! This is Android only though. But it's not quite clear from the question if he needs it for Xamarin Forms or Xamarin.Android AND Xamarin.iOS.